# iOS phone app: third party app integration like Viber/WhatsApp

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

There is some API that allows third party apps to be display as an option in iOS native phone app:

[image: third party integration]

As one can see there is Viber and WhatsApp, and by selecting it will open third party app.

which API is being used here? I've no clue what to search for in order get information how to integrate my voip app with native iPhone app. I suppose some kind of extension. any help on keywords to search for and any example are much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but it is called [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

Comment: The part you want is called: Creating a Call Directory App Extension

Comment: @rckoenes i have already implemented callkit. but couldn't find this option. I think call directly extension sounds much more like it. Thank you very much. i will try it and will post results here.

Comment: according to the documentation: "CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext
A programmatic interface for adding identification and blocking entries to a Call Directory app extension." the information is saved with this extension is only for call blocking and showing caller names instead of phone numbers. so unfortunately that's not what we thought it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to activate this option in native Apps:

First, one has to use CallKit framework. iOS will generate those options(called handles) automatically. The property responsible for that is `supportedHandleTypes` with `CXHandleTypePhoneNumber` handle type.

```
CXProviderConfiguration * config = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:NSLocalizedString(@"myAppName", @"")];
config.supportedHandleTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@(CXHandleTypePhoneNumber), nil];
```

The handle in native app will appear after this configuration is called. I've called this in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

If video handle should be appeared as well then configuration should be:

```
config.supportsVideo = YES;
```

There are two other handle types `CXHandleTypeGeneric` and `CXHandleTypeEmailAddress`, but I could not figure out what changes were caused by those handles. please do comment if you know what they do.

ps: I was using `CXHandleTypeGeneric` before, and I could not see handles for my App. As soon as I changed it to `CXHandleTypePhoneNumber`, the handle was added automatically in contact details.